# split gulpfile with require-dir

Tags: file, split, gulp

I have a problem with split my gulpfile using require-dir module..
In ./gulp directory I have a gulp.js file with task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')

gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('./styles/sass/**/*.sass')
.pipe(sass())
.pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/css/'))
    });
```

This is my gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
gulp.watch('frontend/styles/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);

    });
```

The main problem that all working correctly without errors in console but task dont make nothing (sass dont compile to css)

console.log:

```
[14:37:31] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\pokemongo\app\development\gulpfile.js
[14:37:32] Starting 'watch'...
[14:37:32] Finished 'watch' after 31 ms
[14:38:05] Starting 'sass'...
[14:38:05] Finished 'sass' after 12 ms
```

If I put code in single gulpfile all working perfect..

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to gulpfile split but I got same problem...

**my main gulpfile:**

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var gulp = require('gulp');
require('./gulp/gulpcss.js')(gulp, sass);

gulp.task('watch',  function() {
  gulp.watch('./frontend/styles/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass'])
});
```

**my gulpcss:**

```
module.exports = function (gulp, sass) {

   gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('../frontend/styles/sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../frontend/styles/css/'))

});

};
```

console log ->

```
[14:37:31] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\pokemongo\app\development\gulpfile.js
[14:37:32] Starting 'watch'...
[14:37:32] Finished 'watch' after 31 ms
[14:38:05] Starting 'sass'...
[14:38:05] Finished 'sass' after 12 ms
```

The main problem that all working correctly without errors in console but task dont make nothing again. (sass dont compile to css)

If I put code in single gulpfile all working perfect..